# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while Webscraping with BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to webscrape all snapple facts on https://www.snapple.com/real-facts right now, and since I didnt find anything useful online, I decided to write my own script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.snapple.com/real-facts')

result_list = []
soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find("div", {'id':'facts'})
for div in divs:
    fact_li = div.find('li')
    for fact in fact_li:
        spans = fact.find('span', {'class':'description'})
        for span in spans:
            a = fact.find('a')
            result_list.append(a)

print(result_list)
```

when I run this it returns:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snapplefactscrape.py", line 11, in <module>
    for fact in fact_li:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I get what that means, but I dont understand why the fact_li is an int, and how I can prevent it from being one.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all elements use `find_all` instead of `find`.

You don't need to use 3 loops to get all links, using `select` with `#facts .description a` css selector will give you them:

```
base_url = 'https://www.snapple.com'
data = requests.get(f'{base_url}/real-facts')
soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('#facts .description a')
for link in links:
    print(link.text, base_url + link['href'])
```

But if you want to use loops:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'facts'})
for div in divs:
    fact_li = div.find_all('li')
    for fact in fact_li:
        spans = fact.find_all('span', {'class': 'description'})
        for span in spans:
            a = fact.find_all('a')
            result_list.append(a)
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly! Now if I print the facts it looks like this tho:
<a href="/real-facts/9">The average speed of a housefly is 4.5 mph.</a>
How can I parse this so it gets the number from the href (9 in this case) a comma and after that the fact? Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Every link in `links` is a `Tag`object. In the answer update you can find how to get text and href attribute. [What to do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

When iterating `for div in divs:` div becomes a string. So instead of the bs4 find method on tags, you´re using the find method on strings, which returns -1 if the substring is not found.

IN  the first iteration for example, the value of div is "\n". This would be a good example for  using a debugger to check the value of variables. Or even use print for value and type checks.